# Eclipse Console that shows my REPL doesn't work with tab complete, up/down wrapping, ctrl-c (even though it works in the command line)

Tags: eclipse, shell, console, jruby

So I wrote a shell wrapper for JRuby IRB with some modifications and I'd like to be able to run it from eclipse.

Whenever I run it in the eclipse console, I lose functionality, such as tab-completion, up/down last command wrapping, and ctrl-c support.

If I make a runnable jar, all of this stuff works. It seems to me that the eclipse console doesn't recognize things such as ctrl-c and whatnot.

How would I make the eclipse console emulate a real command line?